# How to extract the config from a kernel image file when CONFIG_IKCONFIG is set as a module (=m)?

Tags: linux, configuration, linux-kernel, arm, kbuild

How do I extract the kernel configuration from a kernel image file?

The kernel image file type is:

> ```
> /boot/kernel7.img: Linux kernel ARM boot executable zImage (little-endian)
> ```

The kernel has been compiled with `CONFIG_IKCONFIG` enabled. However,

```
scripts/extract-ikconfig /boot/kernel7.img
```

returns

> ```
> extract-ikconfig: Cannot find kernel config.
> ```

Note: I am trying the get the config without booting the kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the kernel has been compiled with `CONFIG_IKCONFIG=m` (note the **m**), the configuration in stored in a module (`configs.ko`) and not in the kernel itself. That's the reason why running `extract-ikconfig` on the kernel image fails.

In this case, we can extract the config from the configuration module:

```
/usr/src/$(uname -r)/scripts/extract-ikconfig \ 
   /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/kernel/configs.ko
```